# Video Tutorials for using the site

Tags: discussion, faq, tutorials

During our beta I created a video to kind of explain how the site works. I'd like to continue expanding on that and create other videos for the site if people want to watch to see how they work.

Please feel free to add your own. I use [recordmydesktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast/4433#4433) to make these.

Answer (score 24):

#### [How do I ask questions on Ask Ubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgvXaCY9uek)

This tutorial is how to ask a good question right away so your question is high quality *before* you post it to the site. (Ugh, audio stops working 9 minutes in, I'll need to redo this one)

#### [How to improve your answers on Ask Ubuntu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ptnlogCqOes)

Some tips on how to improve your answers with more detail. (Some video corruption here in some places, bummer.)

---

I made these at 1920x1024 so they show up nice if you fullscreen and want to get into the detail so if you can't read it click the fullscreen button.

Feedback on these as I make them is appreciated, I tend to get opinionated on how certain things should work so if that's obvious in the video and you think it's wrong please let me know. If you're from a sister stack site, please steal. Also, feel free to make your own and add them!

Comment: @JorgeCastro, nice work on these.  For the one on improving questions, I'm a little nervous that there's too much emphasis put on asking questions without details.  Editing in more detail is obviously good, but shouldn't there be some detail in the initial post?

Comment: I [made a list question to get feedback on a list of things to cover via video tutorials](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1040/what-topics-would-be-good-for-video-tutorials/)

Comment: awesome, wonderful

Comment: @Rebecca Ok I made a video just for asking new questions, hopefully that one will help people better.

Comment: Wait a sec, shouldn't the site be so easy to use that you don't need tutorials?

Comment: @alexy13 The videos are more for showing people how to put better content in their questions so that they can get better answers than how to use the site.

Comment: mm... The links are dead... D:

Answer (score -1):

I do know this answer is is not appropriate to the question. But I think it is suitable to mention it in this popular question.

Video tutotials for using the site as well as for **Frequently Asked Questions** would be Fruitful. ( For things like Using terminal, using Software Center, Find applications.etc.)

People find it difficult to change into ***different environment in Ubuntu***. You can see this with questions. Only the people with literacy is high can get benefit from written answers. Certain people are unable to even submit a question. (They are the ***majority*** in the society !).Can refer Questions for those videos even.

***Separate section with hosting video tutorials*** would be beneficial.(I am a videographer and I would happily pay my voluntary contribution if such a thing is there).

Answer (score -1):

I don't agree with having videos. Videos are about explanations and this site is quite simple, click and click. Everything has its name or tooltip so there's no need for explanations. If there's something needing explanation is should not be so complicated that needs verbal means.

Do you really want a site full of videos showing where to click? I don't because it would be a waste of resources.