# What topics would be good for Video Tutorials?

Tags: discussion, tutorials

Jorge Castro has done a great job starting these [video tutorials](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1037/video-tutorials-for-using-the-site) and I would like to help in producing a few myself. However, I'm not sure which topics would be good to cover.

Answer (score 5):

## How and when to Comment

It is common for new users to post comments that should be answers, and answers that should be comments. This video could also show how to directly reply (e.g @JohnDoe) to another user.

Comment: Might not be the most interesting topic ever, but I'd love to see that screencast!

Comment: This video should include @'ing names with spaces, so people know if any special something or other is needed.

Answer (score 4):

## How to ask a question

I figure this is pretty straight forward - though I find myself more and more pointing users to the "Ask Question" button. Hopefully a video showing HOW to ask a question and more importantly describing how to ask GOOD questions will be more informative than the current little "Read this and accept" page.

Comment: +1 for a video showing where the @#$% the "Ask Question" button is, as pathetic as it is to need it. Hopefully there will be an interface change..

Answer (score 4):

## Get moderators attention

While it's rare, occasionally posts need a moderators attention. How to do so, what the different topics and reasons are - in a video may help to release some confusion and help users know *how* to take action against posts.

Possible topics:

- Spam
- Abusive
- Inappropriate
- Close or Delete
- Migrate to another SE site

Answer (score 2):

## The @ symbol and other easter eggs

While some of the other Stack Exchange sites have an immediately comprehensible mailbox/reply icon, this invaluable place to track comments and replies was invisible to me until I accidentally clicked it instead of my name. I only wonder what else I'm missing out on.

Possibly also cover:

- @'ing people when commenting so they get a notification

Answer (score 1):

## Stack Exchange messages

It was a month after regular use of the site before I realised the little StackExchange button in the upper left was a button and was useful