# How do I leave comments on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, faq, comments

How do I leave a comment to an answer on the Ask Ubuntu site?

I posted a question and someone posted an answer. But the answer fails to take into account information posted on the site. How do I present this information in a comment? No way of leaving a comment is offered.

Answer (score 11):

Commenting is a privilege you earn by using the site.

When you reach 50 Reputation, you earn the privilege called *Comment Everywhere*:

- From the [**Privilege description**](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/comment):

  > How do I comment? Click the add
  >   comment link under each post. Comments
  >   cannot be multi-line, so simply press
  >   enter to submit your comment.
  >
  > Note that comments support a small
  >   subset of Markdown, so you can do
  >   things like *italic* and **bold** and
  >   [named hyperlinks](http://example.com)
- Note: you can always comment on every part of *your own question*, even at 1 reputation.

When you comment, the owner of the Post, and - if applicable - the person that's mentioned in the comment (i.e. '@Stefano') is notified via their Global Inbox.

If you are asking a question, and you want to add additional information, it's better to **edit the question** rather than commenting on it. This way, you'll avoid long threads of conversation, which this site really isn't designed for.

If you want to learn more about using the site, we have some brilliant [**Video Tutorials**](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1037/video-tutorials-for-using-the-site).

Answer (score 4):

If you can't comment on your own questions or on answers to your own questions, that almost always means you're logged in as a different user than the one you used to post the question. Log in as the same user.

If you're not a registered user, you can register and then request that the accounts be merged. Then you gain the ability to post comments on your questions and on answers to them, as well as to mark an answer as the accepted answer.