# How do I add comments on answers?

Tags: support, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how do I leave a comment to an answer on the Ask Ubuntu site?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1224/how-do-i-leave-a-comment-to-an-answer-on-the-ask-ubuntu-site)

This may be a stupid question, but I don't get it. I see that all kinds of people leave comments on specific answers to questions.

All I have is an answer box on the bottom of the page. I don't want to reply with a new answer. I want to comment on someone's answer.

I don't see any 'reply' or 'comment' link so I assume that to comment on a particular answer, it must all be done from the one answer box in the bottom with some sort of string like @james123.

I'm going to post this question and then try some things to figure it out since it doesn't say anywhere how to do it.

[image: CANT comment??]

[image: CAN comment?]

Comment: wtf. i have a comment click link on this post, but not others. now i'm even more confused