# The site FAQ should indicate where Ubuntu stops

Tags: feature-request, site-faq

The description of this site's topic in the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) is not very informative:

> Ask Ubuntu is a Q&A site designed to make it easy for users to get answers to Ubuntu-related questions. It's also a place for users to share their knowledge about the Ubuntu Platform.

Here are a few ways in which the site FAQ could be improved:

- Expand “Q&A” to “questions and answers”. Keep it human, not geeky.
- Explain where Ubuntu stops. Are alpha releases on-topic? Are out-of-support releases  on-topic? Are “alternative” releases (Kubuntu and co) are on-topic? Are derivatives (Mint and co) are on-topic? Are issues with applications in universe/multiverse on-topic? Are issues with third-party applications running on Ubuntu are on-topic?
  (I suggest refering to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) for questions that are off-topic.)
- Remove the paragraph on privileges: they're explained below anyway.
- Add a short note with a link to the [faq tag on Meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/faq), something like

  > If your question is not answered here, check our [community FAQ](http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/faq), and more generally our [meta-discussion site](http://meta.askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Your second bullet is dead on, nice idea.

Answer (score 6):

*Here's my stab at an improved version of the moderator-editable part of the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq#questions) (between “What kind of questions can I ask here?” and “Please look around …”). I don't follow AU very closely so I hope I haven't misreported any policy. Feel free to edit this answer to improve on this text.*

---

**Ask Ubuntu** is a questions and answers site for Ubuntu-related questions. It's also a place to share knowledge about Ubuntu.

Please follow the [Ubuntu Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/conduct), [Ubuntu Leadership Code of Conduct](http://www.ubuntu.com/community/leadership-conduct), and this FAQ when participating in this community.

[Video tutorials](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1037/video-tutorials-for-using-the-site) about how to use the site are available.

Please note that:

- This site is about Ubuntu, including [official Ubuntu derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/derivatives). For questions about Linux Mint and other Linux distributions, try our friends at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead.
- If you are running Ubuntu, third-party applications and development are on-topic here.
- If you've found a flaw (a “bug”) in Ubuntu, [report your bug on the bug tracker](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).
- If you have a problem with the next unreleased version of Ubuntu, don't ask about it here; instead follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) to analyze and report it.

If you have a question about the site that is not answered in this FAQ, check our [community-maintained FAQ](http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/faq), and more generally our [meta-discussion site](http://meta.askubuntu.com/).

---

*(alternate version of the on/off-topic list arranged into two separate lists, like most SE sites)*

We welcome questions about:

- using and administering Ubuntu, including [official Ubuntu derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/derivatives);
- running third-party applications on Ubuntu;
- development on Ubuntu.

This is not the right place for:

- Linux Mint and other Linux distributions (try our friends at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/));
- bug reports ([report your bug on the bug tracker](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs));
- problems with the next unreleased version of Ubuntu (follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) to analyze and report it).

Comment: I like it! The only problem I can see is that it's rather long.

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo I've squeezed out some unnecessary wordiness. I prefer the single-list version for the on/off-topic list, but I've also included a two-list version following the format of most SE sites' FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

(Here's my stab at it, making CW so people can polish)

I do fear that it's already too wordy and no one will read it and I'm only making it worse, heh.

---

#### What kind of questions should I not ask here?

You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page. Avoid asking questions that:

- Are really bug reports. A "bug" is a flaw in the software that ships in Ubuntu. Ubuntu uses a bug tracker called Launchpad for bug reports. Usually the best thing to do is to [report this bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) in the right place so someone can look at it.
- While questions about [official Ubuntu derivatives](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/derivatives) are ontopic here, third party derivatives that are not supported by Ubuntu itself (like Linux Mint) are offtopic here, however you can ask our friends at the [Unix and Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).
- Questions about problems with the next unreleased development version of Ubuntu are offtopic here, follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) to report your problem.

If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here. (You are more than welcome to have such discussions in our real time web chat or the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) or [IRC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetRelayChat).) However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.

To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

- every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
- your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
- there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
- we are being asked an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
  it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”

(The above section was adapted from MetaFilter’s FAQ. For more detail, see six guidelines for great subjective questions.)

If your question is not answered here, check our [community FAQ](http://meta.askubuntu.com/tags/faq), and more generally our [meta-discussion site](http://meta.askubuntu.com/).

Comment: You can't edit the “What kind of questions should I not ask here” part, only the first section ([for now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95160/experimental-stack-exchange-faq-improvement-project)).