# Are questions related to ubuntu as it relates to development on topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm working on writing a C-daemon for Ubuntu and I wish to make it configurable but I'm new to linux\ubuntu and I don't know the standard way daemon configuration is preformed. Is AskUbuntu an appropriate place to ask about how daemon configuration generally works?

Comment: I've asked quite a few and they generally get a good reception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a great question, and yes it's absolutely on topic. This site is about using Ubuntu *and* developing on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted my question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55940/whats-the-standard-way-to-provide-configuration-options-for-a-daemon).

Comment: I must say.. you guys have a strange sense of what is "on topic." You can't ask Linux Mint questions.. which is an ubuntu distribution.. but because it's not official, it's off topic. But, for a development question... which in this case is not specific to ubuntu or even Linux.. It is on topic. Lol, ok. I don't wish to argue the point. I just want to make it known i feel it's a bit strange.

Comment: @user606723 This question has a lot to do with how users expect programs to work on Ubuntu, it's perfectly relevant. Unless the fact that someone is using Ubuntu is completely irrelevant, programming questions are okay too, in the same way that it's okay to ask something like [How do I get spaces instead of tabs in nano?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40732/how-do-i-get-spaces-instead-of-tabs-in-nano). Instead of closing, I'd prefer if people just *recommend* the user ask the question on stack overflow.

Comment: By the way, your concern is appreciated. We always *try* to be very consistent, but we don't always manage to be. :-)

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo Nag: [site FAQ update proposal](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1667/the-site-faq-should-indicate-where-ubuntu-stops)