# Google Code Prettify support for Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Reading this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/99668/2732) I've realized that we don't have [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) support on Ask Ubuntu like we have on Stack Overflow.

Since we [agreed](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1692/2732) that we welcome Ubuntu development questions I think we should also have Google Code Prettify support.

Comment: We'd have to make sure it doesn't mess up the bulk of code blocks, which is log files (most of them) and shell scripts (some).

Comment: If we could get it to default to `lang-none` then it wouldn't be a problem. On [so] it infers the language based on the tags. We can have it set via `<!-- language: lang-type -->` if we don't want to have single language tags on [ubuntu.se].

Comment: Ah. That would be great.

Comment: This looks awesome!

Comment: Yes please! I could have sworn that we've asked for this  before, but my search foo is failing me.

Comment: A similar request on Super User: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4266/make-syntax-highlighting-possible-to-enable-with-prettify-language-codes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is done. :)

You have syntax highlighting enabled and moderators can configure the setting for individual tags from their respective tag wiki info pages. The default is "none".

For more info on the finer points of syntax highlighting, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting).