# Why did you close this question instead of migrating it?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, scope

This guy asked about [elementary OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414658/invalid-efi-file-path-windows-7-elementary-os). I voted to notify the moderators, I commented letting him know it's off topic. But why didn't you migrate it to superuser or unix.se?

I'm not trying to defend him. I'm trying to follow this rule written under the [mint](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mint) tag, it clearly says:

> For questions about Ubuntu that mention Linux Mint, an unofficial
>   Ubuntu derivative. Most questions here are off-topic and should be
>   migrated to the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site.

So why didn't you just migrate this one instead of closing it? if It's low quality Superuser or Unix.SE then I'm sure they can close it too.

Comment: You raise a fair point. The tag wiki was incorrect but I've tried to improve it with in line with actual site policy.

Comment: @Oli `Questions that aren't about Ubuntu at all should not be asked here.` now that sounds better, and that solves the issue, thanks Oli :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why didn't you just migrate this one instead of closing it? If It's low quality Super User or Unix.SE then I'm sure they can close it too.

You have actually hit the crux of the issue I have with this question.

The golden rule for migrations - don't migrate stuff you yourself don't regard as high-quality.

There is very little here that could be construed as "quality" information - a bunch of issues with very little detail, errors, logs etc to  diagnose the issues.

The best route for the OP is pointing them towards the correct forum. The notice states just that.

They themselves can look around and see if their question hasn't already been answered.

Answer (score 3):

Migration channels for things like that aren't open.  If they were, it would lead to a flood of migrated questions.

I think the real question, posed to you, is:

> Why is it so hard to re-ask the same question with a copy paste on the appropriate site?

Comment: `Why is it so hard to re-ask the same question with a copy paste on the appropriate site?` it would be that simple, if you didn't ban the asker who have many closed questions, so closing questions isn't that silly

Comment: That comes back to a law of averages thing.  If you read the FAQ and understand the site use, then make a mistake... you won't even feel the bite.

Answer (score 3):

Rules of migration:

1. Don't migrate crap.
2. Only migrate if the target site wants the question.
3. See No. 1.
4. If OP ask to be migrated, let it.
5. See No. 3.

That question violates 1, 3 and 5. ;)

Comment: so what you're saying is that, if i go to that question and tell the user to ask you to migrate it, and if he says what I tell him and tell you to migrate it, would you?

Comment: 1 and 3 tripped first is what he's trying to say I think.  Look at that as procedural logic.

Comment: @Fischer "Don't migrate crap" rule is above all the others.