# Video tutorials timing out

Tags: support, bug, tutorials

Just wanted to let you know that the video tutorials are timing out.

https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.

[Video Tutorials for using the site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1037/video-tutorials-for-using-the-site)

Comment: Pretty sure that's outside our purview of control, as we don't control blip.tv, and I don't think we keep copies of the videos around...

Comment: And in all likelihood, the interface has changed a lot since 2011, so the videos won't be all that useful.

Comment: I just thought that it could be edited out.

Comment: @ThomasWard mods can edit that page, right?

Comment: @ThomasWard I think muru meant removing the "*If you wish, you can even see several [Video tutorials](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1037/video-tutorials-for-using-the-site) on how to use the site.*" line from here: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: @pomsky that was unclear because "that page" could mean any page :P

Answer (score 2):

I contacted Jorge and he has two of the videos up on YouTube.  Unfortunately the other two are lost to time.

I've updated the links to the two videos that he still has.